# create an empty obj from model.schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to build a data migration feature for my software. the client is providing data in csv format. I have built the field mapping based on my schema-model. The plan is to create an API which will return me an empty object for the model and I update the object with data collected from the CSV.

I understand that model.schema.obj will return me the schema, but that will have all the declarations for each field. I need my API to return an object based on the schema with all values set to undefined or empty string.

Can anyone help me ? Please

Comment: are you using Mongoose or any other ODM?

Comment: yes I am using Mongoose :)

Comment: Cool, check my answer, that should work ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of your model with the default values to empty/undefined/null (you decide) and the return it.

Here's an example using Mongoose:

```
// Define your model
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = Schema({
  name         : { type : String, default:'' },
  lastname     : { type : String, default: '' }
}, {collection: 'user', usePushEach: true});
```

Then on your API endpoint create an instance of the model and return it (example assuming you're using Express).

```
getSchemaObj: function(req, res, next){
  var emptyUser = new User();
  res.json(emptyUser);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it. give me some time. will come back soon.

Comment: Just tested it... Brilliant. Sometimes the answer is just in front of us but we need to ask for help. thanks a lot... :)